# Linkage error when using static library in executable

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, static-libraries, conflicting-libraries

I am trying to build an executable which should be linked with the

1. mosquitto (`libmosquitto.a`)
2. json-c (`libjson-c.a`)

Also, there is a custom C API built as a static library as well: `myCAPI.a`
My linux is *Ubuntu 18.04* running under virtual machine. Also, I am using `cmake` tool.
So, when I'm trying to build an executable I am getting the following linking errors:

```
myCAPI.a(some_client.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol 'valueTypes' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
libmosquitto.a(connect.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
// etc.
libjson-c.a(strerror_override.c.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against '.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
// etc.
```

I have a googled a lot and find some articles where it is said that the issue is connected to **gcc**'s version (either *PIE* or *PIC* is selected as an option). So, I tried to build my environment as follows:

```
cmake -no-pie ../
```

Also in this way as well:

```
cmake -fPIC ../
```

Here is my CMakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(EXAMPLE_NAME "PublishValues")
project(${EXAMPLE_NAME})

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.c")
include_directories(include ../../include )

set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libtvcmiclient.a libmosquitto.a libcares.a libjson-c.a libssl.a libcrypto.a libpthread.so libdl.so)
link_directories(../../3rdparties ../../libs)

add_executable(${EXAMPLE_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${EXAMPLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS})
```

Unfortunately, the linking errors still there.

Comment: `cmake -fPIC` `cmake` is not a compiler. Please show your configuration. Please show your `CMakeLists.txt`. How do you link with `json-c`? How do you build the libraries? How do you build the executable? Please create an [MCVE] (On a side note, it's not nice that cmake just ignores unknown arguments :/ )

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I know, but shouldn't I give this options to the cmake tool? I guess cmake will inject the option to the created Makefile and when I do 'make' it will consider that option, isn't it?

Comment: The phrase "recompile with -fPIC" refers to the **libraries** you use, not to the your project. Literally, you need to have `libmosquitto.a` and `libjson-c.a` be compiled with `-fPIC`.

Comment: @KamilCuk The static binaries describe in the CMakeLists.txt already existed: I didn't build those. I link with json-c statically as you can see from the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. (How is making a screenshot easier then copying text?) Please copy and paste the text as text in your question. `but shouldn't I give this options to the cmake tool?` [CMAKE_C_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_FLAGS). But really just google "how to pass compiler flags to cmake"...

Comment: @Tsyvarev I already have those static libraries (including myCAPI.a) compiled and I cannot recompile those, as I don't have any source code of the myCAPI.a). Also, as I understood static libraries are already compiled with -fPIC option and I just need to compile my .exe with that option.

Comment: @KamilCuk OK, sorry, I didn't know about that, but making a screenshot as easy as copy the text (windows+shift+s)

Comment: "Also, as I understood static libraries are already compiled with -fPIC option" - No, your understanding is wrong. These libraries currently are NOT compiled with `-fPIC`. If rebuilding them is not an option, then you need to compile your executable **without** PIE (`no-pie`).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I could compile it finally.